# Returning the next results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table that is something like the one below.

```
id  | episode_number

1        55
2        56
3        57-58
4        59
5        60
6        61-62
7        63
8        64
9        65-66
10       67-68
```

My goal is, whenever a certain episode is chosen. I would like to return the next 5 results. Lets say, if episode_number 60 is chosen, I would like to return the the next 5 results which is

```
id  | episode_number
6        61-62
7        63
8        64
9        65-66
10       67-68
```

I have achieved this by doing the following statement below, everything works great.

```
$query = $PDO -> prepare("SELECT * FROM table
                          WHERE `table`.episode_number > :episode
                          ORDER BY (`table`.episode_number + 0)
                          LIMIT 5");

$query->bindValue(':episode', 60, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

But how about if the chosen episodes are not INT but actually a STR? such as 61-62, how would I return it's next 5 results?

Comment: do you mean `61-62` itself counts 2 number? so we just need to get more 3 (instead of 4)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, when you have a string, then you are getting that value in the "next" list, rather than the "next" value.  If this is the problem, here are two ways to solve it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE `table`.episode_number + 0 > :episode
ORDER BY (`table`.episode_number + 0)
LIMIT 5;
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE `table`.episode_number >= :episode
ORDER BY (`table`.episode_number + 0)
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: Nope, lets say I put `table`.episode_number > 55, this will work just fine. But if I put `table`.episode_number > 61-62. It would not return the desire results. Since 61-62 is not actually a valid number but a string, unlike 55.

Comment: @KuwameBrown . . . How does it not work?  Edit your question with the results you are getting and the actual results.  The database will convert between different types.

Comment: 61-62 is not an INT, therefore the database will somehow consider it as 6. And I get the next 5 results after episode number 6. The DASH is what makes the difference.

Comment: Interesting.  That means that the variable substitution doesn't work the same way as literals in the query do.  You can test what literals do with:  `select (case when '7' >= 64 then 1 else 0 end)`.  It makes a big different if `:episode` is a an integer versus a string.  As an integer, I would think it would cause `episode_number` to convert to an integer as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you meant, can you update your answer above. Something that I can try. Please